# Correlation Size

Tags: correlation

If I want to make an argument that two stocks are reasonably correlated:

Q1. What is the most credible source (most cited) of correlation size for stock return pairs?  What is a reasonable small, moderate and high in value?

Q2. In determining correlation, should one use daily return or weekly return?

Q3. How long a time series should one use to be reasonable?